# CSS Navigation bar problems

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvSRT.png) [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TtrF.png)     [problem I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Ig5.png)I have been having a AWFUL time trying to fix my html/css code to get the "logout" button to be displayed side by side with the search bar, icon and the rest of the navigation bar elements. It fits in perfectly if I make it an anchor tag, but because I need it to be in a form, I need it to be a submit button type. The only thing that seems to work is giving it a negative top margin which is not ideal since the more you compress the page, the higher up the button goes. I have no idea how to fix this and am in desperate need of some assistance.

Comment: Please post a working example of the problem  without an example it will be hard to get help

Comment: Please post relevant code to reproduce issue.

Comment: I have posted the html/php & css code responsible for the issue. It seems like for some reason, the position of the logout button is fixed below the rest.

Answer (score 0):

> Set display flex for nav/chid element to be side by side.

```css
.navbar { 
     display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <form action="#" class="navbar">
        <input type="text">
        <button>Button</button>
    </form>
</div>
```